# Error booting installer usb: '/boot/' not found

Tags: boot, system-installation, uefi

I bought a cheap Atopnuc Linux box, and I've been having trouble with my Ubuntu system. So I decided to reinstall it. I downloaded ubuntu-22.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso, and burned it to a memory stick using BalenaEtcher, a Macintosh app made for the purpose of burning such things.  (Trustworthy app?)

I go to my Linux box, F12 gets me to a UEFI menu, and it offers may, among other things,
UEFI: ASolid USB, Partition 2
Immediately it tells me

> Error: file '\boot' not found

But from a virtual machine Linux, I see that this device does indeed have a /boot directory. How to look into this? Is it a problem that it found /boot on Partition 2, not Partition 1?

Here is a partial listing of that directory, hopefully the most useful parts:

```
ken@parallels-Parallels-Virtual-Platform$ pwd
/media/ken/Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS amd64
ken@parallels-Parallels-Virtual-Platform$ ls -lR /boot
/boot:
total 179756
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   270012 Apr 21 10:56 config-5.19.0-42-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   275587 Aug 18 05:38 config-6.2.0-32-generic
drwx------ 3 root root     4096 Dec 31  1969 efi
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root     4096 Sep 19 06:32 grub
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       27 Sep 19 06:25 initrd.img -> initrd.img-6.2.0-32-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 73105652 Sep 19 06:22 initrd.img-5.19.0-42-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 69432627 Sep 19 06:30 initrd.img-6.2.0-32-generic
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       28 Sep 19 06:25 initrd.img.old -> initrd.img-5.19.0-42-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   182800 Feb  6  2022 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   184476 Feb  6  2022 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   184980 Feb  6  2022 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw------- 1 root root  6437157 Apr 21 10:56 System.map-5.19.0-42-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  7969006 Aug 18 05:38 System.map-6.2.0-32-generic
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       24 Sep 19 06:25 vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-6.2.0-32-generic
-rw------- 1 root root 12201064 Apr 21 10:59 vmlinuz-5.19.0-42-generic
-rw------- 1 root root 13791304 Aug 18 05:40 vmlinuz-6.2.0-32-generic
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       25 Sep 19 06:25 vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-5.19.0-42-generic
ls: cannot open directory '/boot/efi': Permission denied

/boot/grub:
total 2400
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 May 18  2022 fonts
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     712 Apr 19  2022 gfxblacklist.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root    9996 Sep 19 06:32 grub.cfg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root    1024 Sep 18 16:45 grubenv
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   12288 May 18  2022 i386-pc
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 May 22 12:12 locale
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2392289 May 22 12:11 unicode.pf2
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   20480 May 22 12:12 x86_64-efi

/boot/grub/fonts:
total 2340
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2392289 May 22 12:12 unicode.pf2

/boot/grub/i386-pc:
total 2496
<skipping LONG list>

/boot/grub/x86_64-efi:
total 3500
<skipping LONG list>
```

Comment: Did you hashcheck the downloaded ISO?  Don't know about BalenaEtcher, but try Rufus.